# Android: external storage permission issue:

Tags: android, permissions, sd-card

I really need someone here to guide me about some issues with the external storage OR sd-card. I won't go into complexities. I have a folder with the name of `MyVideos`. It is located in the sd-card folder of Motrola Xoom; the path is `"/mnt/sdcard-ext/MyVideos.` The folder is already there. However, there are some strange errors I am having.. For example, if I check if the folder exists or not using the following code:

```
File myDirectory = new File(defaultStorage, "/MyVideos/"); 
if (myDirectory.exists())
{  
my code: lets say true
}
else
{
my code: false
}
```

where `defaultStorage is = "/mnt/sdcard-ext"`. It always return false. It should return true since the folder surely exists there. And assuming that the folder exists there, I perform other operations like

```
for (File f : myDirectory.listFiles()) 
    {
        if (f.isFile())
        {
            filenames.add(f.getName()); //add to array

        }//if closes
     }//for closes
```

I get FATAL exception at the following line

```
for (File f : myDirectory.listFiles())
```

The error stack is below:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(22644): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity         
E/AndroidRuntime(22644): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I have just mentioned the things that are important from the stack. It is a NullPointerException to be precise. Although I am using

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

in my manifest file. Even then it doesn't work. The most **surprising** element is that it is running fine here; but there is a client in USA, it is crashing on all his devices.. Is there any difference in the permission settings of devices in UK or in USA.. I shall be thankful to you if you help me here.. It is a big problem for me.
Thanks

Comment: where defaultStorage is = "/mnt/sdcard-exe".  Is that a typo in the SO post or in the code?  (final 'e' instead of 't')

Comment: How do you obtain the value of `defaultStorage`?

Comment: I suggest you not to use hardcoded path, but get it using the `getExternalStorageDirectory ()`

Comment: @Nikola Despotoski: The problem is that getExternalStorageDirectory returns /mnt/sdcard whereas I need the actual path of external storage which is /mnt/sdcard-ext and there is no API in android that can get me the absolute path of removable sdcard.

Comment: @Chris, the defaultStorage path is absolute correct. I have tested it on myXoom and it is working fine. I confirmed from my client and the path is the same. So, there is nothing wrong with the path.

Comment: @Farhan - the path is absolutely incorrect in your post, I'm asking if that error (final 'e' instead of 't') is only in your post or in your code as well.

Comment: @Chris, its typo, he mentioned in the comments that his path is `sdcard-ext` I wonder if that user has mounted card at all? Why dont you add tests to check if the sdcard is mounted at all. I can guess, that NPE is thrown because `File` object is null.

Comment: @chris, yes, in my code; it is /mnt/sdcard-ext "ending with t, not e"..

Comment: @nikola: the card is mounted on my client device and he can play videos stored in that folder on the external sd card.. it is just the application can't access it.. whereas the same application can access it in my device having the same path.. Moreover I confirm that the card is mounted; if the card was not mounted then the user wouldn't have been able to open the folder manually and play the video files stored in it.

Comment: Can you post the line where the NPE occurs? And log all relevant data?

Comment: The NPE occurs exactly on the line where the following code is written: for (File f : myDirectory.listFiles())

Comment: If you do `File myDirectory = new File(getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/MyVideos/");`  what does `Log.i("Dir", Boolean.toString(myDirectory.exists());` outputs? I might be overdoing with the fact I think that external common sdcard is load it under `/mnt/sdcard/` without -ext, but we need to find all evidences and relevant ways. Plus what do you do if that dir does not exists?

Comment: Thanks alot to all.. I have resolved the issue. The device that my client had was protected.

Comment: @Farhan - please summarize the issue in your own answer and accept it so that this doesn't keep resurfacing in the unresolved category as it did today.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#MEDIA_SHARED), the state you're describing means that the external media storage isn't accessible to you:

public static final String MEDIA_SHARED

Added in API level 1 getExternalStorageState() returns MEDIA_SHARED if the media is present not mounted, and shared via USB mass storage.

Constant Value: "shared"

You need to go to your USB Mass Storage options and turn off USB storage.

PS : Thanks to DigCamara I copied from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15820148/cannot-write-to-sd-card-on-android-phone).

Thanks